# Is there a CHNTPW alternative for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords

I'm looking for a [CHNTPW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chntpw) equivalent that I can use from Linux to recover, clear or change a Windows password.

`chntpw` is not quite working for me, I'm planning to boot this from portable.

Comment: Is there an error it throws, what isn't working about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ophcrack will likely be able to recover the existing Windows password. http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/